# mobile SDK configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

is it possible to configure the mobile SDK to target a domain other than mkt cloud API domain, so that the communication first passes through our infrastructure and then is "proxied" to the mkt cloud API?

example: 
mobile request -> 
https://APImanager/someMktCloudEndpoint -> https://mktCloudDomain/someMktCloudEndpoint

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share more about the use-case for this and why it would be needed please?

Comment: there are several "dimensions" that can be managed, in our case we want to monitor some like success rates, monitor usage, performance

Comment: I suggest you discuss these things with your account manager.  Analytic data is captured and should cover most of these needs.

Comment: maybe i got it wrong but Is there analytic data being collected by Mkt cloud infrastructure that we could consult? I looked in the sdk documentation site and couldn't find that info. Can you please provide some guidance on how to get it?

Comment: It would depend on what kind of data you're hoping to collect.  See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html.  Things like "time-in-app", "open from push" and all notification analytics are handled if you set analytics to true.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to accomplish this, but it is not supported and based on the comments provided would be completely unnecessary and add complexity in addition to making your implementation very fragile.